# Client side validation script is not generated for partial views fetched using AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I am trying to setup client side validation using MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation
to work with ajax submitted forms.
It works perfectly fine if the partial view is rendered directly from a view.
However when I try to fetch it over XHR, for example to show it in a JQuery Dialog, 
client validation javascript is not generated for the output html.
Any ideas?

Working code - partial view is rendered using Html.RenderPartial:

*View:*

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <% Html.RenderPartial("New"); %>
</asp:Content>
```

*Partial View:*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Product>" %>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation();%> 
<% Html.BeginForm();%>
  <%= Html.EditField(m => m.price)%>
  <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.price)%>
<% Html.EndForm();%>
```

Not working code - partial view is fetched with JQuery load() function.

*View:*

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 ....

 $("#dialog").load('~/Product/New/');
 $("#dialog").dialog("open");

 ....

 <div id="dialog" title=""></div>
</asp:Content>
```

*Relevant controller action:*

```
public PartialViewResult New(int id)
{
  return PartialView(service.GetProduct());
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen for all partial views which return JavaScript inserted into the DOM via AJAX.  The problem is that the JavaScript returned with the partial view is not executed/interpreted when it is inserted into the document.

Unfortunately, because what you are dealing with is generated JavaScript I can explain why you are experiencing the problem but I'm at a loss for a solution.  Were this a function you wrote I'd suggest adding it to the OnComplete.  All I can offer is that this is a JavaScript limitation and to start looking there.

BTW: this looks promising http://adammcraventech.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/asp-net-mvc2-ajax-executing-dynamically-loaded-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

After reading the blog ARM has mentioned it seems the solution really depends
 on how one is loading the partial view.
 What eventually worked for me is to call __MVC_EnableClientValidation
 after view has been assigned to an element:

```
    $.get('~/Product/New/', function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);

        // extracted from MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js
        var allFormOptions = window.mvcClientValidationMetadata;
        if (allFormOptions) {
            while (allFormOptions.length > 0) {
                var thisFormOptions = allFormOptions.pop();
                __MVC_EnableClientValidation(thisFormOptions);
            }
        }
    },'html');
```